# Scraping Yahoo finance historical stock prices

Tags: python-3.x

i am attempting to parse Yahoo finance's historical stock price tables for various stocks using BeautifulSoup with Python. Here is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tickers = ['HSBA.L', 'RDSA.L', 'RIO.L', 'BP.L', 'GSK.L', 'DGE.L', 'AZN.L', 'VOD.L', 'GLEN.L', 'ULVR.L']
url = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HSBA.L/history?period1=1478647619&period2=1510183619&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d'

request = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find_all('table')[0]




n_rows = 0
n_columns = 0
column_name = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):

    data = row.find_all('td')
    if len(data) > 0:
        n_rows += 1
        if n_columns == 0:
            n_columns = len(data)


    headers = row.find_all('th')
    if len(headers) > 0 and len(column_name) == 0:
        for header_names in headers:
            column_name.append(header_names.get_text())


new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_name, index = range(0,n_rows))


row_index = 0
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    column_index = 0
    columns = row.find_all('td')

    for column in columns:
        new_table.iat[row_index, column_index] = column.get_text()
        column_index += 1

    if len(columns) > 0:
        row_index += 1
```

The first time i ran the code, i had the interval set to exactly two years from November the 7th 2015 (with weekly prices). The issue is that the resulting data frame is 101 rows long but i know for a fact it should be more (106). Then i tried to change the interval completely to the default one when the page opens (which is daily) but i still got the same 101 rows, whereas the actual data is much larger. Is there anything wrong with the code, or is it something Yahoo finance are doing?

Any help is appreciated, i'm really stuck here.

Comment: I've been gathering some historical data as well, but the data is usually limited to what the API provides. Its not like you can retrieve data in each and every minute that occurred since 2015. Just saying, I haven't verified, buts its what I would expect.

Comment: But you can actually manually download the weekly stock prices and get more than 101 weekly observations. I just want to make sure that it's the API that is limiting the data or if something is wrong with the code.

Comment: You could use a library built for this purpose: https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this seems to do the trick. Do you have any idea if i can download the weekly prices using data_reader. I tried using resampling using as frequency but the results do not match the ones manually downloaded from yahoo finance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the API was shut down in May of 2017.  Can you use Google finance?  If you can accept Ex cel as a solution, here is a link to a file that you can download to download all kinds of historical time series data.

http://investexcel.net/multiple-stock-quote-downloader-for-excel/